# LiveKernelEvent and ParameterService

Tags: windows-10

I have a 3-year-old Acer Aspire E5-575T-58WH laptop that's running Windows 10. For the past few days, my laptop's screen turned white and froze. I didn't update any hardware. I am not a game player.

```
A problem with your hardware caused Windows to stop working correctly.

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: LiveKernelEvent
Code:   144
Parameter 1:    3003
Parameter 2:    ffff8102387ed5c0
Parameter 3:    40010002
Parameter 4:    0
OS version: 10_0_17763
Service Pack:   0_0
Product:    256_1
OS Version: 10.0.17763.2.0.0.256.4
Locale ID:  4105

Description
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Windows\System32\IntelSSTAPO\ParameterService\ParameterService.exe

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   ParameterService.exe
Problem Signature 02:   0.5.8.275
Problem Signature 03:   570c3d1c
Problem Signature 04:   ParameterFrameworkFacade
Problem Signature 05:   0.5.8.275
Problem Signature 06:   570c3cfb
Problem Signature 07:   16a
Problem Signature 08:   15b
Problem Signature 09:   ParameterServer.ServerException
OS Version: 10.0.17763.2.0.0.256.4
Locale ID:  4105
Additional Information 1:   1923
Additional Information 2:   192325ccdd99758e9a3116bb3c9da948
Additional Information 3:   9d79
Additional Information 4:   9d793c6018da015948564a373688da1a

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:  82e0878b41cca42c41613120dd38943e (129152566098)
```

Comment: Update BIOS, Chipset, and Video drivers as these need to keep up with Windows Updates

Comment: Thank you very much, John! it work perfectly fine now.

Comment: Thank you. I have posted an answer for you here.

Answer (score 0):

Update BIOS, Chipset, and Video drivers as these need to keep up with Windows Updates. It appears that has fixed your issue.